# Using ajax to send rowID and append selected rows to new table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Currently trying to take a row with a specific ID number and, if the row is checked, allow the user to click a button and append these specific rows to a new table in order to do comparisons, etc. The rows are all generated in a table using php and my code is only about half complete but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is my current jquery:

```
   $(function(){
      var rows = [];
      $('compareRowButton').click(function(){
      $('.compareRow:checked').each(function(){
        var ele_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
          type : 'post',
          url : 'compare.php', //query 
          data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, // passing id via ajax

          success : function(data){
            rows.push(data);
          }
        });
      });
      $('.displayTable').click(function(){
        // append to table or divs
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and here is what I have in compare.php:

```
<?php
include_once('functions.php');
include_once('link_costreport_2013.php');
sec_session_start();
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
    $id = $_POST['post_id'];
}
    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM `s10`
                            WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch();
    ?>
```

I'll admit I had some help with the jquery/ajax so my understanding of how it works is lacking a little, but a few things I don't understand fundamentally are:

1. How can I turn my fetched results into the 'data' parameter that gets pushed into the 'rows' array. I'm guessing this is on the PHP side.
2. How do I parse the 'data' and have it display in my table in `<td></td>` elements under the right headers and such? The ID is obviously just one part of the entire query but there are about 6-7 columns worth of data for each ID.

At the end I'm just trying to display the new table with the selected rows and hide the old one.

If I can provide any additional information I'd be glad to, wasn't sure what else to include.

Thanks in advance

::EDIT::

```
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                $id = $results['id'];
                $rowID = $results['id'];
                if($results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care'] != 0){
                $charityPortion = ($results['233_net_charity_care'] / $results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care']);
                $baddebtPortion = ($results['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts'] / $results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care']);
                } else {
                    $charityPortion = 0;
                    $baddebtPortion = 0;
                }
                echo "<tr id='$rowID'>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='$id' value='$id' class='compareCheck' name='post_id[]'></input></td>";
                echo "<td>".$results['provider_num'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td><a id='$id' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>".$results['provider_name']."</a>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>\$".number_format($results['233_net_charity_care']);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>\$".number_format($results['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts']);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>\$".number_format($results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care']);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>".sprintf("%.1f%%", $charityPortion * 100);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>".sprintf("%.1f%%", $baddebtPortion * 100);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
```

This is how the final fields are calculated. Is it possible to call modify the formatting like so in the script?

Comment: You could probably improve it a great deal by only doing one ajax request, something like -> http://jsfiddle.net/vycnexj2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` on the PHP side to encode the fetched results:

```
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Then to display the results, turn the JSON array into a row of the table.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'compare.php', //query 
    data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, // passing id via ajax
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){
        var row = "<tr>";
        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            row += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
        });
        row += "</tr>";
        $("#tableID").append(row);
      }
    });
```

If you only want to display selected columns, have PHP return an associative array:

```
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);
```

and extract the columns you want:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'compare.php', //query 
    data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, // passing id via ajax
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){
        var row = "<tr>";
        row += "<td>" + data.id + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + data.provider_num + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + data['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts'] + "</td>";
        row += "</tr>";
        $("#tableID").append(row);
      }
    });
```

Comment: This works but I guess I didn't necessarily tell you how my database is set up because I didn't realize that the solution was to iterate through the returned php/json array like you have done for the `$.each` function. I will post the way that I call the fields in the original tables in my original post so you can see, but for instance the last 2 fields that I have are calculated based on the results in previous ones. Like I said I'll add it to the original post and try to explain the process a little better.

Comment: If you want to add additional columns, just do that after the `$.each()` loop.

Comment: Or you can do it in the PHP, before you send the results to the client.

Comment: Another option is to have PHP create the HTML for the `<tr>`. There are many ways to do this, they're all pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ok, that part makes sense then. Is there a way I can control the range of the i value for the iteration?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If you don't want to return all the columns, change `SELECT *` to `SELECT <list of columns>`. Or return it as an associative array instead of a numeric array, so the Javascript can pick out the columns it wants to display.

Comment: You can also use `if (i == 3) { return; }` to skip column 3, for instance.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having a separate compare.php for all of my pages (they call different columns in the same table) if I don't have to. Could you possibly show me what it looks like to append an associative array result as opposed to a numeric one?

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: if I may ask one more question though: Would data['id'] and data.id , data.provider_num and data['provider_num'] reference the same thing? What is the reasoning behind that particular syntax?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent. I generally use `object.property` when the property is literal, and `object[property]` when the property is a variable. But `object.propert` can only be used when the property name is an identifier, so I have to use `data['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts']` because `291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Alright, I should definitely rethink the naming of my table headers on that note, they were complicated enough as is. Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Barmar answer is fine but can we put for loop for the row as I am having multiple rows with same id and I want to show all of them in table can you please say

Comment: @G.Lakshmi If the API returns an array of rows you can use a loop.

Comment: @Barmar once see this fiddle I wrote the code of html and php and ajax of how I did now I am trying to select all the rows having same id and append into that table 
please see fiddle and say https://jsfiddle.net/62s7ocr3/1/

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't select multiple rows with the same ID.

Comment: @G.Lakshmi Use a class instead of ID.

Comment: I mean selecting all rows with same id from db

Comment: where are you saying as class @Barmar

Comment: I have a tbale with id and groupid and some data id is primary key and I want to select the rows with same groupid and append them to the table using ajax @Barmar

Comment: @G.Lakshmi SOrry, I assumed you meant the same HTML ID in each row.

Comment: If you have a problem, you should post a question, we shouldn't discuss your problem in comments here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218355/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-barmar).